# how do I loop something in java?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program for my class, and I can't quite seem to figure out how to loop it. so i haven't quite gotten the whole swing of loops, i would like to see an example of how i would add a loop to rerun this program repeatedly unless 999 is entered

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Evan {

public static void main (String[]args) {


String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a evan number");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt( input1);


if (num1==999)
    System.exit(num1);

if ( (num1%2) == 0 ) 
System.out.println("Good Job!");

else  {
    System.out.println("HEY thats not evan try again");

}

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in using a for loop or while loop?

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. What action(s) exactly you want to loop? What are you trying to achieve (what is your code supposed to do)?

Comment: `while(true)`??

Comment: @Pshemo I think he wants to iterate from the input declaration until the end of the main method.

Comment: Just use a while(true) as @AntonH suggested

Comment: `for(;;){//your expression here}` for an infinite loop?

Comment: The work is spelled 'even'. And like AntonH said, just wrap all the logic in a while(true) loop

Comment: the for loop just takes in double semicolons indicating an infinite loop

Comment: @martinomburajr I think a while(true) loop would work better here.

Comment: @AlexCuadrón That may be true and it is reasonable guess, but it is still a guess, so I would prefer clarifications from OP.

Comment: @RougexTitan Use [edit] option to update/clarify your question.

Comment: why use while(true) and then system.exit()? Perhaps right way is while(num1!=999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use the right condition for the while.

```
  Integer num1 = 0;
  while (num1 != 999) {
     String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a evan number");
     num1 = Integer.parseInt( input1);

     if ( (num1%2) == 0 ) 
       System.out.println("Good Job!");

    else  {
       System.out.println("HEY thats not evan try again");
    }
}
System.exit(num1);
```

Comment: OK THANKS!! this really helped out big time!

Answer (score 0):

Surround the part of your code that should be repetitive with `while (true)`, which makes it go on forever (the `System.exit(num1)` will still exit, though you should probably replace that with `break;`).

```java
while (true) {
    String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a evan number");
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt( input1);


    if (num1==999)
        System.exit(num1);

    if ( (num1%2) == 0 ) 
    System.out.println("Good Job!");

    else  {
        System.out.println("HEY thats not evan try again");

    }
}
```

Comment: ok i see how that works my teacher tought us to use the system.exit(); but i think ill just use break since its less typing :) thanks!!